# HTMX POST request for a form is working, but there's no field data included

Tags: htmx

I have a form that should submit a POST request containing the form field data, but when the backend app receives the request, its blank (no data). Why isn't it working?

```html
<form hx-post="/meme">
    <label for="name">Funny meme name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="rating">Funniness rating</label>
    <input type="number" id="rating">

    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

The form fields are missing their `name` attributes. Form fields are only included in a POST request if they have a `name` attribute set. E.g. `name="funny_meme_name"`.

Here's the code with names set.

```html
<form hx-post="/meme">
    <label for="name">Funny meme name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

    <label for="rating">Funniness rating</label>
    <input type="number" id="rating" name="rating">

    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```